# best way to retrieve URLs from a mail body

Tags: javascript, office365, outlook-addin, office-addins, office-js

The following line was making add-in non-responsive on Mac clients. The add-in works absolutely fine on mac client if we remove this line and execute the function `someFunction` directly.

> Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync("html", someFunction);

We used `body.getAsync()` because we need to extract all the URLs in the mail body by processing the html and those urls containing certain IDs.

tried using the below but didn't give the expected URLS.

> var links = Office.context.mailbox.item.getEntities().urls;

I am also trying the following

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        app.initialize();
        Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync("html", processHtmlBody);
    });
};

function processHtmlBody(asyncResult) {
    var htmlParser = new DOMParser().parseFromString(asyncResult.value, "text/html");
    var links = htmlParser.getElementsByTagName("a");       
}
```

Is there a better alternative to fetch the URLs from the mail body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tried both alternatives/workarounds with `makeEwsRequestAsync()` and `getEntities().urls` to retrieve the URLs from the mailbody on a Mac client. But both were not successful:

- `makeEwsRequestAsync()`: "no data error".
- `getEntities().urls` : did not give the intended result/URLs

So for Mac client, we ended up changing the logic and added conditional logic which did not include any code to retrieve the URLs.

> if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("mailbox", 1.3))
> {
> //conditional code
>
> }

Answer (score 1):

Note that getAsync is part of the 1.3 Mailbox Requirement set, which Outlook for Mac doesn't currently support:

https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/tutorial-api-requirement-sets.html

Otherwise using Entities is your only option, but getElementsByTagName would probably work best (if you had access to the email body).

Comment: makeEwsRequestAsync() is not giving the expected result since it is operating on Office.context.mailbox not on the item. It's not retrieving the same like getAsync(). Are we missing something?

Comment: That depends on what EWS operation you are calling with makeEwsRequestAsync().  For example, you could call GetItem to get the message body of the current email or any other (provided you have the ID).

Comment: the ID of the email?

Comment: would something like the following work?  Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(
    GetItem(mailbox.item.itemId), callback); ?

Comment: getEntities() doesn't give the expected URLs like when retrieving these using the getAsync() approach.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolved it in a similar way:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mailbox.item.body.getAsync(window.Office.CoercionType.Html, asyncResult => {
        if (asyncResult.status == window.Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            var $dom = $(asyncResult.value);
            var url = $dom.find('#x_hiddenURL').text();

            resolve(url);
        } else {
            reject(new Error('Failed to load email body'));
        }
   });
});
```